# iphone large icon 512x512 with border glitch?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

I just uploaded my first iPhone app. The app icon has a border, sort of like the "settings" icon. However, when I upload my large icon in iTunes connect, there are some weird white edges in the corners. It appears that they might use a smaller corner radius or something. How can I make sure it will display correctly on the apple store?
The image is a jpeg with no transparency.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is the appstore is expecting a purely square 512x512 image.  It then masks it  to have rounded corners and then adds a drop shadow automatically.

If you want it to have a specific border like what you've designed you need to match their rounding exactly.

If you search around. there are PSD templates available that will help you design it (i.e. they have the exact mask that itunes uses).

Here's an example: http://www.pixelresort.com/blog/app-icon-template/

Comment: That's not what is happening in this case.  Instead, it's a bug with iTunes Connect, not necessarily an issue with the icon. Though, kudos for the reference to the PSD template.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique which can work really well is leaving the outer part of the icon square — in your case, the dark brown outer border would extend to the edge of the canvas – and let the roundrect mask handle the corners for you. There's a bit more info in this excellent blog post: [All the sizes of iOS app icons](http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes)

You'd still get the border effect, but let it be cut cleanly by the mask rather than by your icon's transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be a **bug with iTunes Connect**. I've seen the same problem, but it only appears on the Versions summary screen.

I've seen this when uploading a square icon.  For example:

[image: LMGTFY Icon]

**In summary, don't worry about it.  Your icon should still show up correctly in the iTunes Store and on the Devices themselves. If your icon looked clean in the iOS Simulator and on your device, you're good to go.**